# How to restore mysql privileges after bad chown

Tags: mysql, permissions, centos, root

wrongly i set owner on all the files in my server to root :

```
chown -R root /
```

now i have some problem with mysql server due to permission.

How can i set mysql owner to the correct files?

(I can't reinstall mysql server cause i have important table in my db )

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On my CentOS box, the own and group is `mysql` and the install is here. This will fix your mysql permissions.

`chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

However, `chown -R root /` is no doubt going to have caused you a few more problems than simply MySQL.

Comment: The format of chown is `chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...` so `-R` need to be after chown and before user:group.

Comment: I did that, and now I cannot execute `sudo service mysql start` anymore.

Comment: Was about to post this as answer, this did it for me.

Comment: A quicker command. 

`chown -R mysql: /var/lib/mysql`

Is shorter than the above answer. chown user: without the group also sets the group to the username so mysql: becomes mysql:mysql

Comment: My 5.7 install on Mac 10.14.3 had the user and group as "_mysql" (note the underscore). Also, my issue was simply trying to access certain tables causing the server to crash, so for me it was


```shell

chown -R _mysql: /usr/local/mysql/data
```